# tkz-euclide.sty cannot be found

Tags: linux

I am trying to use `tkz-euclide` package. I am using Fedora 16. Installed TeX Live. Everything is working well. Paths are OK. Unfortunately when I try `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}`, it says `tkz-euclide.sty` cannot be found.

I checked that it is actually installed by the command:

```
tlmgr show tkz-euclide
```

So what is the problem here? Any ideas?

Comment: have you run `texhash` or `mktexlsr` or whatever is applicable? (Not sure if this is needed, I don't use TL)

Comment: Yes I did try both.

Comment: Is that error the first one?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? The exact error is: ! LaTeX Error: File `tkz-euclide.sty' not found.

Comment: Most probably it is a path issue. The package is located at `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide.sty` And the path is: `/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/deniz/.local/bin:/home/deniz/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux` According to TeX Live this should be OK. Does anybody know how to set the path properly so that these packages are recognized?

Comment: If you copy the style file into the folder where your tex document is, it should compile. The files can be downloaded from [here](http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/download.html). That doesn't answer your question but should allow you to do your work.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. The problem was, apart from TeX Live, the TeX package that comes with the Linux distro was installed as well. I removed all the distro packages.